# When Executing EXE in Vb.net with refrence of Dll complied in C sharp is throwing error message.

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

I have complied a DLL in C# and took the reference of that DLL in other exe of Vb.net and Now when i am trying to debug that exe it is throwing a error and exe is not getting properly executed.

Error Message is : "The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or with out debug information" Then a path is given in the message "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\DllFolderName\\

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: 1) Unchecked the optimize code option in the build option at properties.    2) Cleaned both the projects and deleted all the dependent files and rebuild the DLL and took the refrence again but it didnt worked.

Comment: It is *not* an error message, just a debugger notification that tells you that the DLL will not be debuggable.  Do **not** use the GAC on your dev machine, it serves no useful purpose.  Remove it again.  Instead use File > Add > Existing Project and select your C# project. Now you can debug the C# code as well and any changes you make to that code will be effective when you press F5 again.

Comment: Okei thank you but for now i have deleted the GAC assembly and took the refrence again and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Right, click your class project > Properties > Advanced > and Make
   sure Debug info is set to full.
2. uncheck "Just My Code" in Tools->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: visual studio 2010

Comment: Hey i just reolved the issue.. :)

Comment: i went to C:\windows\assembly and the i deleted the Gac assembly of my dll and it owrked like a charm.... Between thanks alot for the suggestions..